# Brute Force in java

Tags: java, brute-force

Okay I know how brute force works can anyone explain me how to implement it/create it in java. If possible I don't need the original source code, I just want to understand the algorithm. Can anyone please?

Comment: Brute-force isn't an algorithm. It's an approach to solving problems by guessing every possibility.

Comment: This is the equivalent of "how do I write a book?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force isn't an algorithm, it's a general problem solving technique. If i'm going to solve a problem with brute force, all it means is "I'm going to try every combination possible until I find the solution".

Here's an example. The question is "What is the sum of all numbers between 1 and n?"

Brute force solution:

```
int sum = 0
for i in range(n):
    sum += i
return sum
```

And here's a more elegant solution:

```
return n*(n+1)/2
```

"Brute force" is just a description, not an algorithm.

Comment: Okay thanks now I understand brute Force is a logic applied in terms  we don't know the  certain specifications and we try whatever possible. Thanks very helpful. But can you tell me anything about the for loop you used. I basically use this {(int i=*;i<*;i++)} or sometimes the enhanced for loop. But what is this one?

Comment: This is python, it's just quicker to write. it's the same as "for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)"